# eBay Trading API - GetMyeBaySelling vs GetOrders for getting my sold items

Tags: ebay-api

I need to get the items I sold at eBay **and the detailed information** about each sale (who bought it, their exactly shipping address, email and so on).

I'm wondering, what should I use for that: `GetMyeBaySelling` and `GetOrders`? They seem to be exactly the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GetOrders`, it is made to retrieve all relevant order information. But make sure to use the `Pagination`-Attribute, otherwise the call will only return 100 orders.

Comment: If I have different seller accounts in ebay, so I have to set up different developer accounts in order to integrate in our custom web app?

Comment: I don't think so, you should be able to connect both ebay accounts to your developed app

Comment: We want to integrate in our web app using PHP

Comment: Do you have any links that can help to integrate?